# Reading a Cobol (.cbl) file in python and extract the commented lines from it

Tags: python-3.x, comments, cobol

I am having a .cbl file with many lines. I want to read it and extract the commented lines form the same into a .txt file.

For example:

```
a.  000200* PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
(or)
b.        * PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
```

I need to check for `*` at 7th position. After extracting all the commented lines print it to a text file.

I did this:

```py
with open('AP540P00.cbl', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = set(line)
        if ('*' in s ):
            print(line)
```

But I need to specifically check `*` only at 7th index of every line.

Comment: What you have tried? please, include your code on your answer, the community role is to help, not to do it for you, avoid asking low-effort question, read this StackOverflow guide about "How To Ask": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I havent worked with cobol files, this is the first time..

Comment: I meant your Python source code

Comment: You also need to check for / in column 7 and the floating comment symbol *>

Comment: x=open('AP540P00.cbl')
for line in x:
    print (line, end='')

I tried this to read the file, and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "*" or "/" in column 7 or "*>" anywhere on the line.
Write to a text file.
Python 3.7

Code:

```
line = ''
fout = open('z:comments.txt', 'wt')
x = open('z:code.txt', 'rt')
for line in x:
    if len(line) > 6 and (line[6] == '*' or line[6] == '/' \
                or line.find('*>') > -1):
            fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

Input:

```
000200* PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
      * PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
       code
       code 
      * comment 1

       code 
       code *> in-line comment 
      * comment 2
       code 
       code 
      / comment 3
       code 
       code 
      * comment 4
       code 
       code
```

Output:

```
000200* PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
      * PROGRAM-ID. AP540P00.
      * comment 1
       code *> in-line comment 
      * comment 2
      / comment 3
      * comment 4
```